# How to connect/disconnect from a server?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am using the latest version of boost and boost.asio.
I have this class:

```
enum IPVersion
{
    IPv4,
    IPv6
};

template <IPVersion version = IPv4>
class Connection
{
private:
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator iterator;
public:
    Connection(std::string host, std::string port);

    virtual void connect() { iterator = resolver.resolve(query); } // Is this the moment where the client actually connects?
    virtual void disconnect() { /* what goes in here? */ }
};
```

Should I call `io_service::stop()` and then on my `Connection::connect()` call `io_service::reset()` first before I resolve the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, once you've made a call to `io_service::run`, there's often few reasons to call `io_service::stop` or `io_service::reset`.

In your code above, the `connect` method is *not* going to actively establish a connection - `tcp::resolver::resolve` merely turns a query (such as a hostname, or an IP address, etc.) into a TCP endpoint which can be used to connect a socket.  You typically need to dereference an iterator returned by `resolver::resolve` and pass it to a `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket` object's `connect` method (or one of the asynchronous varieties) to connect an endpoint.

The Asio tutorials have a good example of this.  See the first synchronous TCP daytime server example here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime1.html.  Note that the code first runs:

```
tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
```

to turn a query object into a TCP endpoint, and then:

```
socket.connect(*endpoint_iterator++, error);
```

to connect a socket object on that endpoint.

As for what should go in your `disconnect` method, that's entirely dependent on the application.  But usually you'll need to keep track of an active connection by encapsulating a `socket` object, which you can close as necessary when you call `disconnect`.  For an example of this, have a look at the tutorial titled "Daytime 3 - An Asynchronous TCP daytime server" here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3.html